# Cocoapods error: metadata.rb:15:in `initialize':

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

Got an error when I `pod install`,

Error Message:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.7.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:15:in `initialize': 
undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #<String:0x00007fd25897c8b8> (NoMethodError)
```

Do I need to reinstall Ruby?

Ruby: ruby 2.6.3p62

Pod:  1.7.1

Comment: It seems that you don't have `activesupport` gem installed. Cocoapods make use of active support library for some extra functionality, which includes the method: `with_indifferent_access`. 

You can install it, using: `gem install activesupport` - and here you can see that requirement for activesupport gem: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Core/blob/1.7.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb

Comment: @JonathanDuarte Thanks but it's not my case. I've figured out, this error is because I messed up my private repos `~/.cocoapods/repos/`

Answer (score 1):

As I wasn't using any library installed via CocoaPods, I decided to remove all local repositories and afterwards it worked like a charm. To sum up, I've performed following commands:

```
rm -vrf ~/.cocoapods*
pod install --verbose
```

Comment: this is working fine